# How to made a correct confusion matrix?

Tags: performance, computer-vision, average, precision, confusion-matrix

I made a Haar-Cascade train for made a poop detector now I'm working in the confusión matrix with my own data set my real problem is IDK how to really made the matrix because I have 110 test images that look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMOqn.jpg)

All the images have a poop or 2 poops in the middle and the background is cement. So when i tested my images i have a good precision but i only have TP, FP, and FN values but I never had a TN because all my pics look like the pic that i put in the description and also i only work with one object class (Poop) so can i make a confusion matrix without having a TN values ? someone can explain me how is the real process for made the confusion matrix please

Comment: Do you have any other class apart from poop in your dataset? Are all the pictures in your dataset is of poop ?

Comment: No, i don't have other class I only trained the Haar-cascade model for detect Poop

Comment: and yes my dataset for test only have poop. The 110 test pictures look similar like the picture I index in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have two classes, **poop** and **non-poop**.

To get the confusion matrix you have to also test the model on images without poop and then you can get your TN, which is where the model correctly predicts the **non-poop** class.